# Migrate bbpress content to posts

Tags: content, import, migration, export, bbpress

I'm looking for a way to migratie a bbPress forum to post & replies.
Why you ask? Well... the use of a forum in this case is an overkill. And I want to get rid of it. It's a bad apple from the past.

```
bbPress   migrate to   Wordpress
forums       >         category
topics       >         post
replies      >         comments
```

Is this possible without SQL queries and such? If not... is this straight forward when I give a programmer the task to migrate?

I'm just trying to find my bearings here. Maybe there is some crazy tool out there that I don't know about.

Cheers, 
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself using the following plugin, though if you have 1,000's it may be beneficial to use SQL queries.

[bbPress Topic to Post Converter](https://github.com/jmdodd/bbpress-topic-post-converter) ([Here's the specific code](https://github.com/jmdodd/bbpress-topic-post-converter/blob/master/includes/ucc-btpc-loader.php#L127))

Comment: apparently it's broken under 3.8... wel the functionality is not visible in the dashboard.